# Can wet package depend on dry package?

Tags: ros, catkin, catkin-package, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am wondering if wet package can depend on dry package?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57677/can-wet-package-depend-on-dry-package?/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-03-10

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nope. The old rosmake (dry) system is aware of the catkin ecosystem, but not the other way around.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-03-10**:
Is the main reason for this is to get rid of rosmake as quick as possible?

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-03-10**:
The main reason would be so that the new system doesn't have all the terrible hacks the old system had underneath it. The new system is more linux-like with a more standard build/install structure -- making it aware of the older, non-standard approach would cause a massive mess.

**Comment by [jackcviers](https://answers.ros.org/users/19050/jackcviers/) on 2014-12-13**:
So, what if the packages you need are only provided as dry packages? Do you have to convert them first?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-12-13**:
Either that, or use rosmake for your package.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-12-15**:
The other reason catkin pkgs do not depend on rosmake is that they don't provide all of the necessary exported information for catkin packages to build on top of them automatically. However, rosmake packages do export pkg-config files, which you could try to use, but at your own risk.